# How to populate automatically an array in Java. With specific number of each character

Tags: java, arrays, populate

I would like to populate this array automatically with a certain number of each character.

For example 30 indexes with `@`, 20 indexes with `%`. the "empty" arrays will be `.`.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char grid[][] = new char[20][40];
        Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Let's start playing:");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                grid [i][j] = '.';
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An empty index would be ".". NOT empty array. Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear. It is a 2D array. what do you mean by 30 indexes and 20 indexes?

Comment: what are the task requirements? in the question it sounds like filling an array while the code has a 2D array, so in what way does it need to be filled?

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, grid.length).forEach(i -> Arrays.fill(grid[i], '.'));`

Comment: It is a 2d array. So at the moment [0][0] is ".". [0][1] is "." and so on. I would like to populate 20 fields with %. 30 fields with * for example. [0][4] is "%". and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you'd like to randomly distribute the characters across your array. I'll continue to assume that the values 30 and 20 are guidelines and not absolute.
Since you have a 20x40 array which can store 800 characters and of that there should be about 750 dots and the other 50 the other characters, the distribution would then be 93.75% of `'.'`  , 2.5% of `'%'` and 3.75% `'@'`. Using `java.util.random` something like this could be a sarting point:

```
import java.util.Random;
....


public static void main(String[] args) {
    char grid[][] = new char[20][40];
    Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    System.out.println("Let's start playing:");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            double r = rand.nextDouble();
            grid [i][j] = r < 0.025 ? '%' : r < 0.0625 ? '@' : '.';
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```